# Firebase Storage Image retrieval

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Is it possible to view images uploaded to Firebase Storage in the dashboard?

I want to send some information from the user (images that were processed) to a Firebase Storage, so that if the user experiences a crash I can check out the images that may have caused it as the developer.

Comment: i think you need try firebase remort config feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entire page in the Firebase Console of your project dedicated to show the files in Firebase Storage: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/storage/files

If the file metadata indicates that a file is an image, it will be viewable in the console. But even if the metadata is wrong/incomplete, you can download the file and view it locally.